# Traducir los mensajes de error de Stripe en Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, stripe

alguien sabe como traducir y gestionar los mensajes de error de Stripe en Laravel 5.5?

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe

            Session::flash('danger', $e->getMessage());
            return view('frontend.prices');
        }
```

me devuelve el mensaje correcto del fallo pero en inglés, lo necesito en español. Stripe lo tengo en español y el locale de la app también lo tengo en español. El script del checkout stripe también lo tengo en español. Miré la docu de stripe pero no encuentro la solución.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si alguien se encuentra en el mismo problema, lo solucioné en el archivo ApiRequestor.php ( dentro de Vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib ):

```
 private static function _specificAPIError($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $resp, $errorData)
{
    $msg = isset($errorData['message']) ? $errorData['message'] : null;
    $param = isset($errorData['param']) ? $errorData['param'] : null;
    $code = isset($errorData['code']) ? $errorData['code'] : null;


    if($code === 'incorrect_number'){
        $msg = 'El número de tarjeta es incorrecto.';
    }
    if($code === 'invalid_number'){
        $msg = 'El número de tarjeta no es un número de tarjeta válido.';
    }
    if($code === 'invalid_expiry_month'){
        $msg = 'El mes de caducidad de la tarjeta no es válido.';
    }
    if($code === 'invalid_expiry_year'){
        $msg = 'El año de caducidad de la tarjeta no es válido.';
    }
    if($code === 'invalid_cvc'){
        $msg = 'El código de seguridad de la tarjeta no es válido.';
    }
    if($code === 'expired_card'){
        $msg = 'La tarjeta ha caducado.';
    }
    if($code === 'incorrect_cvc'){
        $msg = 'El código de seguridad de la tarjeta es incorrecto.';
    }
    if($code === 'incorrect_zip'){
        $msg = 'Falló la validación del código postal de la tarjeta.';
    }
    if($code === 'card_declined'){
        $msg = 'La tarjeta fué rechazada.';
    }
    if($code === 'missing'){
        $msg = 'El cliente al que se está cobrando no tiene tarjeta.';
    }
    if($code === 'processing_error'){
        $msg = 'Ocurrió un error procesando la tarjeta.';
    }
    if($code === 'rate_limit'){
        $msg = 'Ocurrió un error debido a consultar la API demasiado rápido. Por favor, avísanos si recibes este error continuamente.';
    }

    switch ($rcode) {
        case 400:
            // 'rate_limit' code is deprecated, but left here for backwards compatibility
            // for API versions earlier than 2015-09-08
            if ($code == 'rate_limit') {
                return new Error\RateLimit($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
            }

            // intentional fall-through
        case 404:
            return new Error\InvalidRequest($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 401:
            return new Error\Authentication($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 402:
            return new Error\Card($msg, $param, $code, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 403:
            return new Error\Permission($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        case 429:
            return new Error\RateLimit($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
        default:
            return new Error\Api($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp, $rheaders);
    }
}
```